# How to print a large incompletely filled array only till last entered int (in C)?

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, int, printf

I'm using `int er[3001]`. I'll be taking user input, but it is unlikely that entire array size will be used.

In a `char` array / string, one would simply set a for loop testing `arr[i] != \0`. How is this effect achieved for an `int` array ?

I'm assuming using the same exact condition won't work?

Comment: You should keep track the range of filled elements using another variable.

Comment: How will you take user input? I want to write an answer according to that.

Comment: @MikeCAT Actually I am converting a char arr into an int arr , and ofc I take input of the char arr using fgets()

Comment: Note that you can use `arr[i] != '\0'` for strings because "strings" in C is a name for null-terminated character sequence, but you cannot use it for general `char` array just as you cannot do for general `int` array.

Comment: @MikeCAT Ah I see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I'm assuming using the same exact condition wont work ?*

You're right in this, there's no *default* sentinel value for marking the end of integer array. You need to either:

- Keep track of the # of elements entered successfully
- Initialize the array with an *invalid value* (let's say, `-1`, when all expected inputs are non-negative) and get to the first invalid value location after the input.
- Use a user-defined sentinel value in the input itself to mark the end of the input.

Comment: @MikeCAT your suggestion and this answer has convinced me to just use a variable to track number of inputs

Comment: Sourav Ghosh & @MikeCAT I need help. Later, I want to take an integer input from the user into an integer array with scanf() { very important to use scanf, since value will be terminated by whitespace } ... Without having the user actually enter a count , is it possible to make a loop that will take only as many inputs as the user gives ( generally, a for/while loop will have a condition like while i <= sizeof( arr ) - I cant use that because I dont know in advance how many integers the user will Enter, all i know is that the max is 3001).

Comment: @JakeFry What help?

Comment: Sorry I was in the middle of writing the comment, now i've completed it

Comment: @JakeFry That sounds like you want to go for a mix of approach 1 and 3, keep a counter, and check for something like `while (input != -1 && count < 3001)`, where the `-1` indicates user has no more entries to enter.

Comment: I'm sorry , I didn't quite get that Sourav...  Could you perhaps explain how that -1 would work ?

Comment: @JakeFry Sure. let's say, user have values `10`, `20`, `30` and `40` to be entered. So, the user enters `10`, `20`, `30`, `40` and `-1`. The last `-1` entered by user will mark the loop as done and exit.

Comment: Oh I got it... I'll implement an if statement in the for loop which will break it if something, say -1 , is entered ! Got it !

Comment: @JakeFry if Sourav's answer was helpful (and I think it was, since they answered also to an extra question) consider accepting it. ;)